# Automatically close command line window after executing an .ps1 File via batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to automatically close command line window after executing an .ps1 File via batch. (The batch works, but the windows is not closing/disappering after execution)

Here´s the batch:

```
cd C:\
powershell.exe -noexit "& C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test.ps1"
exit
```

What do I have to change or add?

Comment: Um... what about removing `-noexit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `start` command to solve your problem.

Code:

```
start "" powershell.exe -noexit "& C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test.ps1"
```